# Why is my .change() function inside jquery plugin is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I am trying to make a simple age calculator. It simply adds the age on the side of the input. It calculates the age that is inside the input by datepicker.
The .split is not very clean but it is just to change date format.

I am guessing my problem is a problem of scope.

What I d like, is my plugin to update the age on change of the input. Here it is:

```
 (function ($) {
        $.fn.ageIt = function () {
            var that = this;
            var positonthat = $(that).position();
            var sizethat = $(that).width();

            //Add div for ages
            var option = {
                "position": " relative",
                "top": "0",
                "left": "300"
            };

            var templateage = "<div class='whatage" + $(this).attr('id') + "' style='display:inline-block;'>blablabla</div>";
            $(that).after(templateage);
            var leftposition = (parseInt(sizethat) + parseInt(positonthat.left) + parseInt(option.left));
            var toposition = parseInt(positonthat.top) + parseInt(option.top);

            $('.whatage' + $(this).attr("id")).css(
                {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: toposition + "px",
                    left: leftposition + "px",
                    "z-index": 1000,
                }

                ); 

            //uptadateage
            function updateage(myobj) {
                var formateddate = myobj.val().split(/\//);
                formateddate = [formateddate[1], formateddate[0], formateddate[2]].join('/');
                var birthdate = new Date(formateddate);
                var age = calculateAge(birthdate);
                $('.whatage' + $(myobj).attr("id")).text(age + "&nbsp;ans");

            };

            //updateage($(this));
            $(this).on("change", updateage($(this)));

            //
        }
    })(jQuery);

    function calculateAge(birthday) {
        var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
        var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch        
        return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
    }

    $("#BirthDate").ageIt();
```

Comment: Because you're assigning the return value of `updateage($(this))` as the `change` event handler

Comment: Event listeners take callbacks. A callback is a function you want to execute when the event is captured. You are calling the callback immediately, hence defeating the purpose of a callback.

Comment: If you want to reference the event target, jquery binds it to `this` as long as you are not using arrow function syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
        $(this).on("change", updateage($(this)));
```

means, "Set the handler for the 'change' event to *the result of calling the function `updateage()` with the parameter `$(this)`*. That's a function call. Because you've already captured the value of `this` in the variable `that`, you can write `updateage()` such that it doesn't need a parameter:

```
        function updateage() {
            var formateddate = that.val().split(/\//);
            formateddate = [formateddate[1], formateddate[0], formateddate[2]].join('/');
            var birthdate = new Date(formateddate);
            var age = calculateAge(birthdate);
            $('.whatage' + $(that).attr("id")).text(age + "&nbsp;ans");

        };
```

Then to set up the event handler:

```
    $(this).on("change", updateage);
```

Note that in a jQuery add-on like you're building, the value of `this` will be the jQuery object upon which the method is called. You don't need to make a new jQuery object (`$(this)`, `$(that)`). So it would work to just write:

```
    this.on("change", updateage);
```

Comment: Ok. And it should work for multiple instance in the same page? Thansk.

Comment: @JohnDoe22366 yes, it should.